# auto update table with jquery and animate

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an html table which i would like to auto update via ajax (to my php script) every x seconds. 
I would also like to animate the 1st cell of every row if it is different to the previous value.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: I would start by checking out jquery.com's documentation page. It has a lot of information about ajax calls and animation. Once you have some code worked out, if you're having trouble getting it to work feel free to post what you have. We'll be able to help much more easily if we're troubleshooting rather than writing from scratch for you.

Answer (score 0):

With Prototype, you would use Ajax.PeriodicUpdater()  Docs are here:

http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/PeriodicalUpdater/

Not sure about JQuery, but I would assume they have a similar core function.

Comment: Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater() even... sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery, please refer to these links.

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ - ajax functions

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ - jQuery effects

http://api.jquery.com/animate/ - jQuery animate function for custom animations.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the Javascript `setInterval()` function and configure it to call one of the jQuery AJAX methods, like [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), and use the 'success' callback to compare current values in the DOM with the ones that have been retrieved by the AJAX request and use the jQuery effects library to animate where applicable. This looks like a pretty good write-up on Javascript timer code:

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

I would just be careful about automating (interval-izing?) repeat calls to the server and make sure they're not overloading your server and also not overlapping -- e.g. if the interval repeats while another request is unfinished, you should cancel the previous request, and perhaps consider making the interval longer.